# Rails radio_button_tag always checking the last one of the group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have radio_button group and I want it to be checked when the page loads on the correct value, but it will always check the bottom radio tag.

```
SW
= radio_button_tag :program_type, "SW", data.program_type,  name: "program_type_#{school.id}_#{data.grade}", class: "program_type", "data-attribute" => "program_type"
%br
TA
= radio_button_tag :program_type, "TA", data.program_type, name: "program_type_#{school.id}_#{data.grade}", class: "program_type", "data-attribute" => "program_type"
%br
N/A
= radio_button_tag :program_type, "N/A", data.program_type, name: "program_type_#{school.id}_#{data.grade}", class: "program_type", "data-attribute" => "program_type"
```

How do I properly set the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass true as third option for making the radio button selected

just check below

```
SW
= radio_button_tag :program_type, "SW", true ,data.program_type,  name: "program_type_#{school.id}_#{data.grade}", class: "program_type", "data-attribute" => "program_type"
%br
```